How can I fix jsonwebtoken issues on Render?
I am currently working on an app that I am trying to deploy on Render but I am experiencing some issues and I was looking for some help/advice on what to do.
The app I am working on is a MERN stack and as I try to deploy my app on Render, while my client side is able to render successfully, it's the server side that's giving me the most issues. I encounter issues such as it's not able to find certain modules. I get these errors:
Cannot find module './lib/validateAsymmetricKey'
Cannot find module '.semver'
I tried updating all my dependencies to their latest versions:
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.11.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "graphql": "^16.9.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.7.2",
    "semver": "^7.6.3",
    "stack": "^0.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7"
} 

The first error I get with jsonwebtoken@9.0.2 is "Cannot find module './lib/validateAsymmetricKey'" error. I went through the documentation and noticed it's not getting called properly which I found unusual. I've tried uninstalling semver and I'll get the "Cannot find module: 'semver'" error. I've even tried downgrading the jsonwebtoken but I get the same semver error since it's used in other packages, and so I've ran out of solutions on what to do.
